# how to dynamically fill the datatable for one column static pressures or big

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

This is Array of object stored in itemgroup.

```
 $itemgroup:
        0: {STATIC_PRESSURE:19.85, FAN_DIA:500, FAN_RPM:1400, FAN_SERIES_NAME:AFPV3G, BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE:26.00,…}
        1: {Big:20.19, FAN_DIA:500, FAN_RPM:1400, FAN_SERIES_NAME:AFPV3G, BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE:26.00, FAN_CMH:1000,…}
        2: {Big:141.74, FAN_DIA:600, FAN_RPM:2800, FAN_SERIES_NAME:AFPV3G, BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE:25.00, FAN_CMH:1000,…}
        3: {Big:91.10, FAN_DIA:500, FAN_RPM:2800, FAN_SERIES_NAME:AFPV3G, BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE:25.00, FAN_CMH:1000,…}
```

JQuery datatable
my array of objects ajax response is filled here in datatable

```
 $('#sample').dataTable({

                            "bDestroy": true,
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "aaData": data.itemgroup,

                           responsive: true,
                            "aoColumns": [
                                {"mData":null,
                                  "mRender": function (o) {return '<input type="checkbox" name="active[]" id="active" class="active" >';}
                              } ,
                                {"mData": "FAN_SERIES_NAME"},
                                {"mData": "FAN_DIA"},
                                {"mData": "FAN_RPM"},
                                {"mData" :"BLADE_ANGLE_VALUE"},
                                {"mData": "FAN_CMH"},
                                {"mData": "BKW"},
                               // {"mData": "EL_FREQUENCY"},
                               // {"mData": "STATIC_PRESSURE"},
                                 {"mData":"STATIC_PRESSURE",
                                  "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                     // if(data==STATIC_PRESSURE)
                                       return data ;
                                  // else
                                        //return data ;
                                  },
                                  // "aTargets":[0],
                              } , 

                                {"mData":"outlet_velocity"},
                                {"mData":"velocity_pressure"},
                                 {"mData":"total_eff"},
                                    {"mData":"static_eff"}
                            ]
                       });
```

Please help i have fill column STATIC Pressure with 2 different variable like big and STATIC_PRESSURE dynamically.. So how Can i do?

Comment: Bansai please help me out here..

Comment: how are you generating the data in PHP? you need to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: array([0]=>stdclass object([STATIC_PRESSURE]=>20.19 ......) Like this i have stored in array of objects.. and return from controller like return Response::json(array(
                            'success' => true,
                            'itemgroup' => $myobject
                ));

Comment: Bansi please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically render the column you can use this for the column.

```
{"mData": function ( source, type, val ) {
        if(source.STATIC_PRESSURE){
            return(source.STATIC_PRESSURE);
        }else{
            return(source.Big);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is very straightforward. If `STATIC_PRESSURE` exists this will render it else it will render `Big`.

I didn't knew this existed. Thanks to your question. I learned something new :)

Comment: bansi help me out in other question(roles filter)

Comment: bansi plz help out.. to my other question